# WampSever doesn't start but it used to

Tags: apache, networking, wamp, wampserver

**WampServer** used to start normally without any problems , Since today it doesn't want to start , it stays red , i already checked if there are other programs using **port 80** , but the command **netstat -aon | findstr :80** shows no results , what can i do ? I am using WampServer3.1.0 on windows 10

Here are the lost two lines from the apache error log , notice that the 14th april i used wampserver normally ,and today , 15th april , i can't use it

```
    [Sat Apr 14 23:15:57.139345 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8608:tid 748] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Apr 14 23:16:03.491719 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4040:tid 736] AH00430: Parent: Child process 8608 exited successfully.
```

And here is the error from windows logs , which appears each time i try to launch WampServer

```
    The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user DESKTOP-C77I129\ga_na SID (S-1-5-21-1612724789-3370941347-187498907-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

Comment: Locate the apache error log file. It should tell you why the server can't/wont start.

Comment: If WAMPServer icon is red then neither Apache not MySQL has started. Look at the Windows Event log for errors from both Apache and MySQL and then update you question with those errors

Comment: Did you install anything new on the PC

Comment: i updated my question with what u asked for guys !